# mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource... [snip]

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, while-loop

Here is the error:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a1797699/public_html/event_details.php on line 21

Here is the failing code:

```
<?php
include dirname(__FILE__).'/db_connection.php';
$eventid = $_GET['id'];
$user = $_SESSION['account'];
$sqlevents = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE ID = $eventid";

?>
<html>
<body>

<?php include dirname(__FILE__).'/Header.php'; ?>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="contentleft"> <?
        while($event = mysql_fetch_array($sqlevents)){ //===ERROR
            ?>
            <table  align="center" style="color:white;">
                <th colspan="2"><? echo $event['title']; ?></th>
                <tr>
                    <td>Date</td>
                    <td><? echo $event['date']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Discription</td>
                    <td><? echo $event['discription']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Created On</td>
                    <td><? echo $event['created on']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Created By</td>
                    <td><? echo $event['created by']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Participants</td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><a href="?adduser=<? echo $user; ?>&id=<? echo $eventid; ?    >">Sign up</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table> <?
        } ?>
    </div>
    <div class="contentright">
        <?php include dirname(__FILE__).'/infopannel.php'; ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php include dirname(__FILE__).'/footer.php'; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a1797699/public_html/event_details.php on line 21

Comment: dont use **mysql_*** use mysqli or PDO... also you havent even executed the query... you need to execute it before fetching it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to use `mysql_fetch_array` on a string when it excpets a resource handle.

```
include dirname(__FILE__).'/db_connection.php';
$eventid = $_GET['id'];
$user = $_SESSION['account'];
$sqlevents = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE ID = $eventid";
$result = mysql_query($sqlevents);

// ....

while($event = mysql_fetch_array($result)){/* ... */ }
```

However, if no one has told you this by now you should not be using the `ext/mysql` extension. Its deprecated, use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead. `mysqli` has an api ver similar to `ext/mysql` and supports more features of `MySQL`.. but `PDO` is much easier to work with IMO.

Same thing with PDO:

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM events WHERE ID = ?');
$stmt->execute(array($eventid));

while (false !== ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Maybe add what he can do to solve this? 

Use the query then return the results to an array and perform mysql_fetch_array on the result_array

Comment: maybe also tell the OP of a better way to do it i.e. dont use **mysql_***

Comment: Was in the middle of editing my firend :-)

Comment: wauw how did i forget this.... feel so stupid :S  thnx!